# HOW DO I CHECK IF BOTH $_POST['name']=name AND $_POST['phone']=phone exist in a db row?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
if('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$_POST['firstname']' AND WHERE 
phone='$_POST['phone']''){echo 'their is a match';}
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: What you have at the moment is a malformed string inside an `if`. There is nothing here related to a database. You need to use mysqli/PDO to connect to your database and execute a query. Please do some research before posting.

Comment: I am already connected to the database.  I have done research, but I am a bear of very little brain and I am having difficulty making sense of the seemingly simple practices that make this task possible.

Comment: I have consulted documentation,w3schools, and several youtube videos.  It is incredible that you can move to reduce my points when after doing my due diligence I 'STILL' can't grasp the information and choose to consult an expert..

Comment: if you're already connected to a database, show us that code too, then we can advise you on how to do a query. At the moment your question is too broad.

Comment: This code is highly vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), too. Never ***ever*** take unsanitized user input and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are you are using Object-Oriented MySQLI, your code would look something like this:

```
$phone = ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) && !empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ) ? $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['phone'] ) : null;
$firstname = ( isset( $_POST['firstname'] ) && !empty( $_POST['firstname'] ) ) ? $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['firstname'] ) : null;

//create the mysql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$firstname' AND phone='$phone'";

$result = $conn->query($sql); //query the database

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //check if there are any results
   echo "There is a match.";
} else {
   echo "No matches.";
}
```

Comment: This is still insecure correct?

Comment: @WilliamWilliams It was, yes. I have added real_escape_string to sanitize any input from POST.

Comment: @gh05t - you might want to edit your code a little more. I'd definitely recommend using bound parameters instead of just escaping the string; but in the case above, you need to add quotes around `$firstname` inside the query, else the query will fail.

Comment: echoes no matches even when there is a match?

Comment: @WilliamWilliams I had some errors in the code, which andrewsi has pointed out. I have approved some suggested edits, and the code should work now.